# Query to display +- 2 days of data but return only selected date itself

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I would like to send a MySQL query where I choose a date from my C# programming comboBox e.g. 04/06/2014. Then result should show +-2days including 04/06/2014 itself. i.e. result will ended up showing data from 02/06/2014 till 06/06/2014 (a total of 5 days) in my dataGridView. My MySQL command below shows only the data for 04/06/2014, can someone kindly correct my code? Any help would be much appreciated!

Note: Assuming the `04/06/2014` will be replaced by my C# code `comboBox_stockDates.SelectedItem.ToString()`

```
SELECT Prices_Date, Prices_Time, Prices_Open
FROM tableprices
WHERE Ticker_ID = 732
AND DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('04/06/2014', '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL - 2 DAY)
AND DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('04/06/2014', '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL - 1 DAY)
AND Prices_Date = STR_TO_DATE('04/06/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
AND DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('04/06/2014', '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL + 1 DAY)
AND DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('04/06/2014', '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL + 2 DAY)
ORDER BY Prices_Date ASC, Prices_Time ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SELECT` filters only the column Price_Date and current date. This one should work for you:

```
SELECT Prices_Date,
    Prices_Time,
    Prices_Open
FROM tableprices
WHERE Ticker_ID = 732
      AND Prices_Date >= DATE_ADD (STR_TO_DATE ('04/06/2014', '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
      AND Prices_Date <= DATE_ADD (STR_TO_DATE ('04/06/2014', '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL +2 DAY)
ORDER BY Prices_Date ASC, Prices_Time ASC;
```

For using the indexes of your table effectively (if there are any) it's better to convert the dates before the query as Chris suggested.

Comment: Hi @sreuter, on the 6th line it says `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '+'`, any idea? :)

Comment: The query seems to be correct. Is there any parenthesis from your code which goes into the query?

Comment: Oh, maybe you could try to remove the spaces before the opening parenthesis. I think some servers don't like them ;)

Comment: I put this code directly into MySQL Workbench (without going through my code), and the syntax error popups when I execute it. Okay, i removed the space after the `DATE_ADD` and it works, thank you! :) But my dataset is very huge, it took a very long time to return result. Maybe I will have to look into the other answer..

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote, you aren't using the indexes proper when you calculate on indexed columns. If there are no indexes set one on Prices_Date and calculate the from/until dates before the query.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I'm currently looking into Chris code, but just keeps telling me syntax error. Still trying out.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't do the conversion in C#?  Seems cleaner.

Then it'd be a select from table where date greater than or equal and date less than or equal.

C# Code:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox_stockDates.SelectedItem.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var start = dt.AddDays(-2);
var end = dt.AddDays(2);
```

Then select:

```
SELECT prices_date,
       prices_time,
       prices_open
FROM   tableprices
WHERE  ticker_id = 732
       AND ( prices_date >= [startdate]
             AND prices_date <= [enddate] )
ORDER  BY prices_date ASC,
          prices_time ASC;
```

Will this not work for you?

Comment: Hi @Chris, this seems more logical, but it says there's a MySQL syntax error. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Hi @Chris, it just keeps telling me `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:00:00 AM AND Prices_Date <= 06/06/2014 12:00:00 AM) ORDER BY Prices_Date ASC,' at line 1`, do you see any issue here? I couldn't..

Comment: @Shyuan - possibly because you have to wrap your dates in single quotes (ie: '06/06/2014 12:00:00 AM').

Comment: Chris, yes I tried that, when run the code, it seems to work, but it took longer time than if I do the query directly. I am going to try it again today and see where is the problem. Thank you :)